# Browser (or node ?) adding parameters automatically to http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `node.js` server with `express.js` and everything has been working well so far, but suddenly I have this very strange bug :

My request to the domain base URL that means in my browser I typed

```
http://localhost:9191/
```

appear in express to have the url parameters `/index/hud.html` which by the way have never been used anywhere in my code as I don't have any "index" folder. I don't even have html files because I use jade. This URL is not totally unknown of me (from old code, elsewhere), but is nowhere mentionned in this server. I have made numerous search accross all files to check this.

So here is what happens :

- I tried making a request handler for `'*'` so I could know what was going on :

**The handler**

```
   this.app.get('*', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req);
   });
```

**The req object (part of) :**

```
route: {    
    path: '*',
    method: 'get',
    callbacks: [ [Function] ],
    keys: [],
    regexp: /^(.*)\/?$/i,
    params: [ '/index/hud.html' ]
},
params: [ '/index/hud.html' ] }
```

Which means that my browser somehow wants to get something that is not the URL I typed, or maybe express modified the request ?

- Then I made a handler for this url. My first guess was to redirect it to `'/'` but it made an infinite loop (which means that for my server `'/index/hud.html'` is the same as `'/'`. Please note at this point that I searched and researched in every file, there is no mention of such path anywhere in the code.
- The request catched from `'/index/hud.html'` is a little bit different than the one catched from `'/'`

**The handler :**

```
this.app.get('/index/hud.html', function (req, res)
{
    console.log(req);
});
```

**The request :**

```
route: 
{
    path: '/index/hud.html',
    method: 'get',
    callbacks: [ [Function] ],
    keys: [],
    regexp: /^\/index\/hud\.html\/?$/i,
    params: [] 
},
params: [] }
```

I also tried deleting browser cache and everything (and changing browser) but it seems to really be express that add these parameters somehow... Anyone have an idea what is going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok auto answer :

I had a `index.html` sitting in the root of my public folder.

Apparently, a request to `'/'` asks for a public index file before going to express's request handlers. That means my `'/'` handler could never be called, and so I couldn't be informed that an `index.html` file was served.

Then, on that index file is an iframe asking for `index/hud.html` (didn't find that one through searching :( ) which doesn't exist in my public folder, creating this time an express get request that I could catch with my `'*'` handler, pointing to `/index/hud.html`

So deleting this `index.html` made the request follow the right path, instead of just getting an html file.

Comment: FWIW, if you declare your routes *before* `app.use(express.static(...))`, your routes will get first shot at handling the requests.

Comment: Oh that is awesome, I was wondering if there is any way to avoid this kind of behavior. Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "this kind of behavior" :) It depends on how you want to structure your app: if you want your own routes to take precedence, declare them (or, alternatively, `app.router`) before the static middleware. If you want it the other way around, do the opposite :)